# Can't open any pages in Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help

When I try to open any kind of page in the Tor Browser, the page will load forever and be white all the time. This started to happen out of nowhere some day. I have already reinstalled Tor. Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: _Any_ page, or just hidden services?